# Keyboard shortcuts on tag page

Tags: feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

While you can type in the search box on the tag page and autofilter the tags, there don't appear to be any keyboard shortcuts. It would be useful, I think, to be able to press enter and, if there is a tag with the exact name entered in the search box, go to that tag. This way, you would not have to move the mouse to the correct tag (which is quite small) and click on it.

Answer (score -1):

This feature is already implemented in the main search bar. For instance, if you type "Java" into the search box and hit enter, it will change the query to "[java]" to give you everything tagged as a Java question.

Also, if you are already on the tags page for some reason, and using the *filter* box, you can hit Tab to focus the first result.